# Performance issues with Before INSERT Trigger, is taking lot of time compared to calling the Procedure Directly after insert

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers, xmltype

I have a before INSERT trigger calling my procedure to process the XML in the XMLTYPE fields in the STAGE_TBL and insert the data into PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
I have to go for Before INSERT trigger(I can use Compound Trigger as well but I didnt tried it yet) in order to update the status on STAGE_TBL row based on the outcome from processing the XML.

The issue I am having is my XML can be huge it can have about 100 - 2000 rp_sendRow chunks, if it is huge, then the trigger is taking so much time. I tried with 100 rp_sendRow and it takes about 4 minutes thru trigger. 
But if I disable trigger and insert into STAGE_TBL and then call the XML_PROCESS for the newly inserted record using the ID, then its completing(Process XML and insert into PROCESSED_DATA_TBL) in less than a second from SQL Developer.

I cannot use regular SQL Insert huge XML from SQL Developer as there is a 4000 character limit, as the Database is not on my local, I cannot even use the XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'MY.xml') option so I am using JDBC code to insert huge XML.

I have called the XML_PROCESS directly from JDBC for the same XML and it took less than a second to process and insert into PROCESSED_DATA_TBL

Please let me know why the Trigger is taking time ?

I am using Oracle 11g, SQL Developer 4.1.0.19

```
--Trigger Code
create or replace TRIGGER STAGE_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON STAGE_TBL 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
ROW_COUNT   NUMBER;
PROCESS_STATUS VARCHAR2(1);
STATUS_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(300);

    BEGIN
    XML_PROCESS(:NEW.ID, :NEW.XML_DOCUMENT, PROCESS_STATUS, STATUS_DESCRIPTION, ROW_COUNT);
    IF(ROW_COUNT > 0) THEN
      :NEW.STATUS             := PROCESS_STATUS;
      :NEW.STATUS_DATE        := SYSDATE;
      :NEW.STATUS_DESCRIPTION := STATUS_DESCRIPTION;
      :NEW.SHRED_TS           := SYSTIMESTAMP;
    ELSE--This is to handle 0 records inserted scenario & exception scenarios
      :NEW.STATUS             := STATUS.ERROR;
      :NEW.STATUS_DATE        := SYSDATE;
      :NEW.STATUS_DESCRIPTION := STATUS_DESCRIPTION;
    END IF;    
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
      :NEW.STATUS             := PROCESS_STATUS;
      :NEW.STATUS_DESCRIPTION := STATUS_DESCRIPTION;
      NULL;
    END STAGE_TRIGGER;

--Stored Procedure  
create or replace PROCEDURE XML_PROCESS (ID IN RAW, xData IN XMLTYPE, PROCESS_STATUS OUT VARCHAR2, STATUS_DESCRIPTION OUT VARCHAR2, ROW_COUNT   OUT NUMBER) AS 
BEGIN
     INSERT ALL INTO PROCESSED_DATA_TBL
        (ID,
        STORE,
        SALES_NBR,
        UNIT_COST,
        ST_FLAG,
        ST_DATE,
        ST,
        START_QTY,
        START_VALUE,
        START_ON_ORDER,
        HAND,
        ORDER,
        COMMITED,
        SALES,
        RECEIVE,
        VALUE,
        COST,
        ID_1,
        ID_2,
        ID_3,
        UNIT_PRICE,
        EFFECTIVE_DATE,
        STATUS,
        STATUS_DATE,
        STATUS_REASON)
        VALUES (ID 
              ,storenbr
              ,SalesNo
              ,UnitCost       
              ,StWac
              ,StDt         
              ,St        
              ,StartQty         
              ,StartValue       
              ,StartOnOrder     
              ,Hand    
              ,Order   
              ,Commit    
              ,Sales     
              ,Rec    
              ,Value  
              ,Id1          
              ,Id2          
              ,Id3          
              ,UnitPrice   
              ,to_Date(EffectiveDate||' '||EffectiveTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
              ,'N'    
              ,SYSDATE
              ,'XML PROCESS INSERT')    
        SELECT E.* FROM XMLTABLE('rp_send/rp_sendRow' PASSING xData COLUMNS
                               store            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'store' 
                              ,SalesNo          VARCHAR(20) PATH 'sales'
                              ,UnitCost         NUMBER      PATH 'cost'
                              ,StWac            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'flag'
                              ,StDt             DATE        PATH 'st-dt'
                              ,St               NUMBER      PATH 'st'
                              ,StartQty         NUMBER      PATH 'qty'
                              ,StartValue       NUMBER      PATH 'value'
                              ,StartOnOrder     NUMBER      PATH 'order'
                              ,Hand             NUMBER      PATH 'hand'
                              ,Order            NUMBER      PATH 'order'
                              ,Commit           NUMBER      PATH 'commit'
                              ,Sales            NUMBER      PATH 'sales'
                              ,Rec              NUMBER      PATH 'rec'
                              ,Value            NUMBER      PATH 'val'
                              ,Id1              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-1'
                              ,Id2              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-2'
                              ,Id3              VARCHAR(30) PATH 'id-3'
                              ,UnitPrice        NUMBER      PATH 'unit-pr'
                              ,EffectiveDate    VARCHAR(30) PATH 'eff-dt'
                              ,EffectiveTime    VARCHAR(30) PATH 'eff-tm'
        ) E;    
      ROW_COUNT           := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
      PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.PROCESSED;
      STATUS_DESCRIPTION  := ROW_COUNT || ' Rows Successfully Inserted ';
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        BEGIN
        ROW_COUNT           := 0;
        PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.ERROR;
        STATUS_DESCRIPTION  := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 250);
        END;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        BEGIN
        ROW_COUNT           := 0;
        PROCESS_STATUS      := STATUS.ERROR;
        STATUS_DESCRIPTION  := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 250);
        END;
END XML_PROCESS;
--Standalone Procedure calling XML_PROCESS
SET DEFINE OFF
DECLARE
ROW_COUNT   NUMBER;
PROCESS_STATUS VARCHAR2(1);
STATUS_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(300);
V_ID NUMBER;
V_XML XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT ID, XML_DOCUMENT INTO V_ID, V_XML FROM STAGE_TBL WHERE ID = '7954';
  XML_PROCESS(ID, V_XML, PROCESS_STATUS, STATUS_DESCRIPTION, ROW_COUNT);

  update STAGE_TBL SET STATUS = PROCESS_STATUS,
                                  STATUS_DATE = SYSDATE,
                                  STATUS_DESCRIPTION = STATUS_DESCRIPTION
                             WHERE ID = V_ID; 
END;


XML
<?xml version = \"1.0\" encoding = \"UTF-8\"?>
<rp_send xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
    <rp_sendRow>
        <store>0123</store>
        <sales>022399190</sales>
        <cost>0.01</cost>
        <flag>true</flag>
        <st-dt>2013-04-19</st-dt>
        <st>146.51</st>
        <qty>13.0</qty>
        <value>0.0</value>
        <order>0.0</order>
        <hand>0.0</hand>
        <order>0.0</order>
        <commit>0.0</commit>
        <sales>0.0</sales>
        <rec>0.0</rec>
        <val>0.0</val>
        <id-1/>
        <id-2/>
        <id-3/>
        <unit-pr>13.0</unit-pr>
        <eff-dt>2015-06-16</eff-dt>
        <eff-tm>09:12:21</eff-tm>
    </rp_sendRow>
</rp_send>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two many unknown variables to determine the problem, but with this information I see four (**edited** to include more answers) possible answers:

1) If you are inserting many rows in only one statement (`INSERT ... SELECT`) the trigger will slow performance.

But your standalone procedure call example operates with only one row (`ID = '7954'`), so I assume the problem persist with only one tuple insertion. In this case 1) is not the problem.

2) You have some kind of index on `STAGE_TBL(XML_DOCUMENT)`. When the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger is called the `XMLType` is not indexed and your trigger calls the procedure with a non-indexed version of `XML_DOCUMENT`. But in your standalone procedure example, `XML_DOCUMENT` is inserted and indexed, so the procedure uses the index.

Complex indexes on complex objects can be used by oracle optimizer not only when selecting data from a table, but they can be used when processing the data itself. This means: if you have an index on a particular data it can be used by a procedure that use this data. And Oracle's `XMLType` are complex objects that can be indexed in many, many ways (see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDCGACG).

I think that XMLTABLE function is being optimized when XML_DOCUMENT is actually inserted in STAGE_TBL.

You can test it by calling your standalone procedure with a XML_DOCUMENT not extracted from STAGE_TBL (or any table that could index the document). In this case both, trigger and standalone, performances should be similar.

**EDITED**: You comment that you have tested the second answer and the performance problem persists. So I include a third option:

3) You have included a XML validation check constraint in `STAGE_TBL`. And this validation is the source of the performance difference. The standalone example does not validate the XML document, but the insert validates it.

You can check if this is what is happening by disabling the trigger. If the insert without the trigger is still slow then the problem is not the trigger, but it is the XML validation.

**EDITED**: You comment that you have tested the third answer and the performance problem persists. So I include a fourth option:

4) In (https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526907) a performance problem with XMLTable is described when working with big XML documents. They comment that using TABLE(XMLSequence()) approach is better in these cases, because XMLTable creates big intermediate results, and TABLE(XMLSequence()) does not.

So in your `INSERT` statement change your `SELECT` from:

```
SELECT E.* FROM XMLTABLE('rp_send/rp_sendRow' PASSING xData COLUMNS
                           store            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'store' 
                          ,SalesNo          VARCHAR(20) PATH 'sales'
                          ,UnitCost         NUMBER      PATH 'cost'
                          ,StWac            VARCHAR(20) PATH 'flag'
                          ,StDt             DATE        PATH 'st-dt'
                          ...
                          ...
                          ,EffectiveTime    VARCHAR(30) PATH 'eff-tm'
    ) E;
```

To:

```
SELECT value(e).extract('//store/text()').getStringVal() store,
       value(e).extract('//sales/text()').getStringVal() SalesNo,
       value(e).extract('//cost/text()').getNumberVal() UnitCost,
       value(e).extract('//flag/text()').getStringVal() StWac,
       to_date(value(e).extract('//st-dt/text()').getStringVal(),'YYYY-MM-DD') StDt,
       ...
       ...
       value(e).extract('//eff-tm/text()').getStringVal() EffectiveTime
  FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(xData, '/rp_send/rp_sendRow'))) e;
```

Comment: I have tested the standalone procedure to process the XML document which is not from any table and that was executed pretty fast similar to the one which is fetched from STAGE_TBL. I have used JDBC to call the Stored Procedure directly, in order to send huge XML as input to the procedure.

Comment: @java-ocean I have included a third possible answer. Please, test it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I do not have XML Validation constraint on my STAGE_TBL. I have already tested with disabling trigger and the insert is pretty fast.

Comment: coming to your first point, I am not inserting many rows, as I am still in testing phase, I just inserted 1 row and that itself is taking about 4 minutes for 100 rows thru trigger

Comment: Are `STAGE_TBL` and  `PROCESSED_DATA_TBL` related directly by a foreign key or indirectly by a chain of foreign keys (involving third tables)?

Comment: STAGE_TBL and PROCESSED_DATA_TBL are not having any direct foreign keys, but they both have a common thrid table foreign keys, which is for STATUSes. On STAGE_TBL the only constraint I have is the foreign key on STATUS table and on PROCESSED_DATA_TBL along with Foreign Key on STATUS table I have checks to make sure 6 fields are not null.

Comment: @java-ocean I have included a fourth possible answer. It is based on the use of TABLE(XMLSequence()) instead of XMLTable. Because I have found performance problems reported when using XMLTable with big XML documents, and in these cases TABLE(XMLSquence()) seems to be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for so many solutions, I tried the TABLE(XMLSquence()) than XMLTable(4th possible answer) and I do see a lot of improvement. It has reduced from 4 minutes to 1.5 minutes for 100 rp_sendRow chunks with Trigger. But still even 1.5 minute is high as it locks the table. When I called the same procedure with out trigger then it was pretty fast (in 0.02 seconds)